# Hi, am having trouble on how to code [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False] into [[2,3],[6,2]] in python

Tags: python

How should I code `[False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]` into `[[2, 3], [6, 2]]` in python, where for the first sublist, 2 is where the True index starts and 3 is the sum of `True` elements from where its index starts.

Stuck with this question

Comment: You should provide the code that you tried, it would be better to actually help you understand why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`and `enumerate`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

[(next(g)[0], 1+len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1]) if k]
# [(2, 3), (6, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple loop and a flag to keep track of the last state:

```
l = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False] 

out = []
previous = False
for i, x in enumerate(l):       # iterate over values and positions
    if x:                       # if True
        if not previous:        # and we had a False before, add new list
            out.append([i, 1])
        else:                   # else increment the counter
            out[-1][1] += 1
    previous = x                # update flag for next iteration
```

Output: `[[2, 3], [6, 2]]`

For fun, a one-liner alternative using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

out = [[(l:=list(g))[0][0], len(l)]
       for k, g in groupby(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1]) if k]
```

Answer (score -1):

check this code

```py
lst = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, False]

result = []
start_index = None
true_count = 0

for i, value in enumerate(lst):
    if value:
        if start_index is None:
            start_index = i
        true_count += 1
    elif start_index is not None:
        result.append([start_index, true_count])
        start_index = None
        true_count = 0

if start_index is not None:
    result.append([start_index, true_count])

print(result)
```